# For any finite group $G$, is it always true that $ b_0\cdot b_1 \cdot\cdot\cdot b_{n}=b_0?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For a finite group $G=\{a_0, a_1, ..., a_n\}$, if we define $b_i=a_j$, does there always exist an arrangement for the index $i$ and $j$, such that $b_0\cdot b_1 \cdot\cdot\cdot b_n=b_0$?

My attempt:

This holds for all Abelian groups since we can switch the order for the multiplication. For example, since the group is closed, we have $$a_0\cdot a_1 \cdot\cdot\cdot a_n=a_k$$

$$\Rightarrow a_{k}\cdot a_0\cdot a_1 \cdot\cdot\cdot a_{k-1} \cdot a_{k+1}\cdot\cdot\cdot  a_n=a_k$$

So we can define $b_0=a_k, b_1=a_0, b_2=a_1 ... b_n=a_n$, then we have

$$ b_0\cdot b_1 \cdot\cdot\cdot b_{n}=b_0$$

But what about non-Abelian groups?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144359/discussion-on-question-by-mathfail-for-any-finite-group-g-is-it-always-true-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.